# Vmware installation over ubuntu sever 12.04 lts

Tags: 32-bit

How to install  vmware workstation 7.1.6-744570.i386 on Ubuntu Server 12.04 lts.

i installed it but error is coming .

Vmware kernel module updater Unable to build kernel module.

See log file /tmp/vmware-root/setup-8887.log for details.

make[2]: *** [/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [*module*/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-27-generic-pae'
make: *** [vmmon.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory`/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only'

please provide the solution for this

Answer (score 1):

This is a VMware problem.

Some kernel internals relating to the spin lock changed from 2.6 to 3.0 and VMware didn't' back port the changes to 7.1.6.

I dont believe there is a workaround at the moment.